# Python: Comparing elements of a list within a list appears to be returning wrongly

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, compare

Just coding a file comparison program, and came upon this issue. I can't even begin to comprehend why this is happening. I did my best to google and search for the issue, but it's a little hard. When this code runs:

```
while a < len(filehashes) and b < len(inphashes):
    if filehashes[a][1] == filehashes[b][1]:
        print(filehashes[a][1] + ' == ' + inphashes[b][1])
        a += 1
        b += 1
    else:
        print('Inconsistency error')
```

I get this output:

```
ee53f15519619c51f205553c828e7546 == ef53f15519619c51f205553c828e7546
```

`filehashes` and `inphashes` are both *list of list of str* (i.e. `[['honk','donk'],['bonk','ponk']]`).

And while that is the expected content of `filehashes[a][1]` and `inphashes[b][1]`. They obviously don't actually equal each other (`'ee...' != 'ef...'`). What on earth is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing `filehashes[a][1] == inphashes[b][1]`. You are comparing:

```
if filehashes[a][1] == filehashes[b][1]:
```

Note the names, you are indexing into the same structure here. If `a == b` that is guaranteed to be comparing the same object even, but it'll be True for any repeated hash values.

Perhaps you instead meant:

```
if filehashes[a][1] == inphashes[b][1]:
```

If all you do is increment `a` and `b` at the same time and they remain equal, you could just as well use `zip` here:

```
for fhash, inphash in zip(filehashes, inpuhashes):
    if fhash[1] == inphash[1]:
        print('{} == {}'.format(fhash[1], inphash[1]))
    else:
        print('Inconsistency error')
```

Comment: You're entirely right, and I consider myself the biggest dumb dumb. Although I'm sure I checked it over like 100 times, I'm sorry for wasting the time of both of you. Learning about zip was at least pretty fun.

Answer (score 1):

The if condition is `filehashes[a][1] ==`**filehashes**`[b][1]` while the print line is `print(filehashes[a][1] + ' == ' +`**inphashes**`[b][1]`). Note the difference. I'm not clear on what you are asking. I think this answers it. If it doesn't, comment on this and then I'll delete this answer.